# Grails 3.1.1 deployment with JNDI Connection

Tags: tomcat, grails, jndi

i am using grails 3.1.1,  i tried to configure my application with jndi connection like this .. i see on the log, said

`25-Oct-2016 11:41:03.764 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8090]
25-Oct-2016 11:41:03.770 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
25-Oct-2016 11:41:03.771 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 36712 ms`

[Like this](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/jndi/SampleTomcatJndiApplication.java)

because i am using tomcat 8, so my code like this

```
package accounter

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/akyDS");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource)bean.getObject();
    }
}
```

then in `context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/akyDS"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                maxIdle="25"
                minIdle="5"
                initialSize="5"
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
                username="root"
                password="root"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true"
    />

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

but when i try to run my tomcat, i get a log like this..

[catalina log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvgNTv5gx2dMklYTllZd1RWdzg)

but i cannot see my project is success to startup when i  access `localhost:8090/`

i get this error when set level log to `DEBUG`

```
 initialSize=5; maxWait=10000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetwee
nEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=6
0000; testWhileIdle=true; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql
://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding
=UTF-8; username=root; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=3; valid
atorClassName=null; validationInterval=15000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowe
d=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; co
nnectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=ConnectionState; jmxEnab
led=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=60
0000; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alt
ernateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDi
sposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptStat
e=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }]]
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasi
ng JDBC Connection [Lazy Connection proxy for target DataSource [org.apache.tomc
at.jdbc.pool.DataSource@2a6e9140{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultR
eadOnly=false; defaultTransactionIsolation=2; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassNa
me=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=50; maxIdle=25; minIdle=5; initialSize=5; ma
xWait=10000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMilli
s=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdl
e=true; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
accounter?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8; username=r
oot; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=3; validatorClassName=null
; validationInterval=15000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAban
doned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties
=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=ConnectionState; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueu
e=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=600000; useLock=fals
e; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllo
wed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnection
Facade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExc
eptionOnPreLoad=false; }]] after transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Conne
ction to DataSource
```

i get some error after delete this code in `application.yml`

```
dataSource:
    jndiName: java:comp/env/akyDS
#    pooled: true
#    jmxExport: true
#    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#    username: dddd
#    password: ddd@
#      username: ddddg
#        password: ddd@


#dataSource:
#        pooled: true
#        jmxExport: true
#        driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
#        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#        username: "accounter"
#        password: "root"

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
#            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
#            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:accounter
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
#            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:accounter
#            jndiName: java:comp/env/akyDS
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

with delete this code,then i run `grails prod war` after that , i try to deployment again.

i get this error..

```
.java:724) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:70
0) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
 [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
 [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.6]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_10
1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/sprin
gframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.s
pringframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.spri
ngframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Factory method 'trans
actionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExc
eption: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEAS
E.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:11
23) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[sprin
g-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans
-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4
.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEA
SE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(Tra
nsactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory
(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[sprin
g-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565) ~[spring-be
ans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans
-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to insta
ntiate [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Facto
ry method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Il
legalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.
jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEAS
E.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.afte
rPropertiesSet(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:167) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEAS
E.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.<ini
t>(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:124) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration.transactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfigur
ation.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5.CGLIB$transactionManager$0
(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6
2dee341.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.j
ava:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$Bea
nMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-conte
xt-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5.transactionManager(<genera
ted>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.
jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.533 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngi
ne[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:70
0)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean fail
ed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resour
ce [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAuto
Configuration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested excep
tion is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instanti
ate [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Factory
method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Illeg
alArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate
.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.regist
erBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(Sp
ringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run
(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApp
licationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onS
tartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(S
pringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5178)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/sprin
gframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.s
pringframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.spri
ngframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Factory method 'trans
actionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExc
eption: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:11
23)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(Tra
nsactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75)
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory
(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to insta
ntiate [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Facto
ry method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Il
legalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instant
iateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.afte
rPropertiesSet(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:167)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.<ini
t>(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration.transactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfigur
ation.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5.CGLIB$transactionManager$0
(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6
2dee341.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.j
ava:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$Bea
nMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionMana
gerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec1411b5.transactionManager(<genera
ted>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 43 more

26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.535 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.star
tup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomca
t-8.5.6\webapps\ROOT.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.cata
lina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].Sta
ndardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:70
0)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.537 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.
5.6\webapps\ROOT.war has finished in 48,325 ms
26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.539 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8090]
26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.547 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
26-Oct-2016 16:35:15.548 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
Server startup in 48378 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The three log statements at the top have nothing to do with this, and are INFO statements, not errors.

The other output you show is likewise not an error, it's telling you (along with a bunch of config settings) that it is finished with some MySQL connections and is returning them to the connection pool, which is *exactly* what you want to see when using connection pooling. It is showing the URL of the database as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accounter?autoReconnect=true` which is what you're showing from the datasource configured in context.xml.

Omitting all of the connection details it basically says

```
Releasing JDBC Connection ... after transaction
Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Nothing here indicates why you might not be able to access your application from a browser, but as far as database connectivity is concerned, everything looks pretty good.

Comment: but it run well when i change the connection from jndi to jdbc on `application.yml`

Comment: Sure, but without any actual error messages or other useful information there's not much to work with

Comment: i tried to deploy war file to other server, but i still cannot access application from a browser

Comment: That's unfortunate, but again, with zero information about why it's failing, it's still a mystery. Anything interesting in the Tomcat log files?

Comment: maybe i must delete configuration in `application.yml`